# .NET профессионал

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, iis, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте.

Я программист-студент 3 курса. Пишу на .NET/C# уже 1.5 года. Разрабатывал веб-сервисы, приложения, десктоп приложения на WinForms. Но так получилось, что в офисе нет опытных разработчиков, а тим-лид находится в другом городе -- пришлось самому все учить и делать; из-за чего меня терзают смутные сомнения в правильности моего стиля кодинга и "прямоты" рук. Отсюда такие вопросы:

- Как улучшить знания по .NET? В частности, **ASP.NET MVC**, **IIS**, **WPF**? (Рихтера читаю, но достаточно ли его?)
- Где почитать или научиться правильно кодить? Например, банальный код, где **if** в **if**, а этот **if** в другом **if**. (ReSharper помогает избежать такого, но тем не менее)
- Какие приложения или дополнения использовать, чтобы рисовать **UML** в **VS**, **IntelliJ IDEA**?

Спасибо.

Comment: Пример кода в студию (лучше линк на пример)

Comment: @maximka: упрощайте функции! Если у вас много вложенных `if`'ов, это обычно значит, что вы напихали тонну логики в одну функцию. Если ваша функция больше, скажем, 50 строк, попробуйте выделить из неё подфункции. (Даже если эти подфункции будут вызываться только один раз.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Я попробую ответить на более общий вопрос: как правильно развиваться.

Тут есть несколько моментов, на которые нужно обратить внимание:

1. Хорошие источники
2. Упор на получение стабильных знаний
3. Итеративность обучения
4. Относительно четкий план развития
5. Разнообразие тем

Теперь по порядку.

## 1. Хорошие источники

В мире выходит в день десятки книг и сотни статей. Если подходить к процессу выбора необдуманно, то это будет крайне не эффективно. Есть очень много проверенных и качественных источников практически по любой теме. Вот некоторые из них: [Классические книги по программированию](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/03/blog-post.html), [Книги для изучения C#/.NET](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/04/best-books-on-cnet.html), [Книги по дизайну/ООП](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/07/books-on-design-and-ood.html).

Эти списки далеки от совершенства, но могут послужить хорошей отправной точкое. Затем, как и в поиске хороших специалистов, достаточно смотреть на перечень литературы в хороших книгах: там плохого не посоветуют.

## 2. Упор на получение стабильных знаний

С одной стороны, может показаться, что наша индустрия развивается невероятно быстро, с другой же стороны, многие концепции, которые являются "новыми" в мире .NET/Java/C++ известны специалистам десятилетиями. Популярное нынче функциональное программирование старше структурного программирования и ООП, но лишь сейчас набирает популярность.

Нет смысла стараться запомнить миллион фактов из всех возможных областей знаний. Значительно более эффективно получить каркас, на основе которых эти знания можно будет выводить и более эффективно получать новые.

Хорошее знание даже такого высокоуровневого языка как C# позволит быстрее освоить другие схожие языки, такие как Java. Понимание концепций СУБД позволит разрбраться и с SQL Server, и с Postgre SQL, и с Oralcle. Понимание концепций многопоточности позволит эффективно работать на любой платформе, поскольку паттерны синхронизации везде очень похожи.

Этот пункт непосредственно связан с предыдущим: хорошая книга дает не просто сиюминутные знания, там описаны еще и основы, на которых эти знания держатся. Изучение хороших источников позволяет затем учиться быстрее путем [повторного использования знаний](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2012/02/blog-post.html).

## 3. Итеративность обучения

Невозможно изучить с первого раза определенную тему достаточно глубоко. Точнее, это зависит от качества источников и текущих знаний, но в общем случае, подход к обучению, как и познанию в целом, является итеративным.

Восприятие новых знаний сильно зависит от текущего практического и теоретического опыта, и некоторые важные вещи просто не осядут в голове с первого раза.

Книгу Рихтера можно перечитывать несколько раз и каждый раз находиться для себя интересные вещи, на которые не обратил внимания раньше. Философские вещи, типа кодинга, ООП, ФП и тому подобного требуют еще большего времени для усвоения.

Именно поэтому, к тем же самым темам стоит периодически возвращаться и смотреть, как изменяется отношение к этому вопросу со врменем. Это не значит, что нужно перечитывать одно и тоже (хотя это тоже возможно), достаточно иметь подходящий набор источников.

Итеративность процесса обучения имеет ряд положительных сторон. Во-первых, невозможно слишком долго изучать одну тему, нужно иногда давать себе отдых и переключаться на что-то другое. Во-вторых, чтобы добиться более глубого понимания одной темы, обычно нужно копнуть другую. Например, невозможно глубоко понимать C# без понимания CLR/JIT. А чтобы разобраться с этими темами нужно понимание ОС и других низкоуровневых вещей.

Аналогично, чтобы глубже разобраться с ООП, зачастую нужно посмотреть на другие парадигмы программирования, например, глянуть на проблемы структурного программирования и изучить основы функционального программирования.

## 4. Относительно четкий план развития

Не обязательно иметь план обучения, расписанный по дням на 10 лет вперед. Достаточно иметь простую mind map-у, в которой будут обозначены ключевые ветви развития: ООП, Кодинг, Философия программирования, Архитектура, Алгоритмы, Многопоточность, Управление проектами и т.п. (нечто подобное я описывал в заметке ["Увлеченный программист"](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2013/10/passionate-programmer.html)). При этом можно сделать даже подборку материалов в виде книг, статей или курсов, чтобы когда приспичит не пришлось тратить время на поиск подходящих материалов.

Идея в том, чтобы не метаться из стороны в сторону, когда вдруг появится желание взяться за изучение чего-то нового, а относительно четко понимать, в какую сторону следует направить свои интересы и куда переключиться со временем.

## 5. Разнообразие тем

Этот аспект уже упоминался раньше, но хочется акцентировать на нем внимание.

Очень важно соблюдать правильный балланс между глубиной и широтой знаний. Нет смысла бесконечно рыть .NET, нет смысла ограничивать себя только вебом, только ООП, только С++, или только чем-то еще. Более того, зачастую, чтобы добиться более глубоких знаний, нужно копнуть смежные области.

---

Теперь короткий ответы на конкретные вопросы топикстартера:

> Как улучшить знания по .NET? В частности, ASP.NET MVC, IIS, WPF? (Рихтера читаю, но достаточно ли его?)

Смотреть [тут](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/04/best-books-on-cnet.html).

> Где почитать или научиться правильно кодить? Например, банальный код, где if в if, а этот if в другом if. (ReSharper помогает избежать такого, но тем не менее)

Есть несколько хороших книг по этой теме:

- [Code Complete](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=0735619678%2C+9785750200641%2C+9785469008224&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0) Стива Макконнелла
- [Чистый код](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2013/06/blog-post.html) Боба Мартина
- [Эффективная работа с унаследованным кодом](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785845915306&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0) Майкла Физерса
- [Рефакторинг](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785932860458&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0) Фаулера

> Какие приложения или дополнения использовать, чтобы рисовать UML в VS, IntelliJ IDEA?

Инструменты - это в гугл. Тут я бы посоветовал просто познакомиться с UML на примере [UML Distilled](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785932860601&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0) Фаулера, или [Applying UML and Patterns](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2015/03/applying-uml-and-patterns.html) Лармана.

Comment: @maximka мне кажется Чистый код дяди Боба, это именно та книга, которая тебе нужна.

Comment: Тяжелая артиллерия подтягивается :).

Comment: ого какие люди посещают нашу скромную обитель)  Глядишь, и Джона Скита тут увидим)

Comment: Здравствуйте, Сергей! Вопрос был задан относительно давно, и к этому моменту я даже забыл, что имел аккаунт (на то время старом HashCode.ru). К слову, я тогда уже нашел Ваш блог и активно читаю его; как и Вашу книгу по паттернам проектирования. Благодарю за исчерпывающий ответ и рекомендации!

Comment: @maximka Был рад помочь!

Answer (score 3):

Лучше начать с Троелсена, он проще. И подкрепить все это сертификацией Microsoft.

Примерный  план такой:

1. Основы

a. Изучаем Троелсена до 18  главы включительно

b. Сдаем экзамен http://www.microsoft.com/learning/ru/ru/exam.aspx?id=70-483&locale=en-us

2. Доступ к данным

a. Читаем главы 21-24 Троелсена

Сдаем  http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-516

 i. Если на базе одного Троелсена не получается подготовиться к экзамену, тогда дополнительно читаем Джулию Лерман

3. ASP.NET MVC

a. Читаем Сандерсена

b. Сдаем http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-486#tab1

4. Сервисы

a. Читаем Леве http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3822848/

b. Читаем http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/20343905/

c. Пробуем сдать http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-487#tab1

5.  по HTML 5, CSS и jQuery .Можно сразу идти сдавать http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-480

Таким образом мы получаем прокачку по базовым недостающим технологиям + контроль через экзамены. Заодно будет сертификация MCSD WebDev, и задел на MCSD WindowsStore  и MCPD.

Книги по базовым принципам разработки из этого списка, я бы читала параллельно

http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6733562/

http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5800704/

http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3105480/

Answer (score 2):

> Как улучшить знания по .NET? В частности, ASP.NET MVC, IIS, WPF?
>   (Рихтера читаю, но достаточно ли его?)

Рихтера (CLR via C#) - последнее издание - отличное. Я бы рекомендовал осилить его полностью, чтобы понимать, как работает CLR.

> Где почитать или научиться правильно кодить? Например, банальный код,
>   где if в if, а этот if в другом if. (ReSharper помогает избежать
>   такого, но тем не менее)

Тут бы я сделал ход конём, и отправил читать про F#: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com - справа раздел Series. По порядку, читая все все подразделы каждой серии статей. Поможет научиться правильно продумывать алгоритмы, правильно разбивать приложение "горизонтально", на отдельные модули. Затем, если захочется (или потребуется) вернуться к C# - думать в примитивах F#.

> Какие приложения или дополнения использовать, чтобы рисовать UML в VS,
>   IntelliJ IDEA?

Рекомендовал бы использовать приложение "Камера" смартфона, а рисовать на доске маркером. Затем обработать в любом редакторе, заменив рукописный текст наборным, если требуется.

Answer (score 0):

По .NET основная классика [Здесь](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2011/04/cnet.html) Э. Троелсена советую особенно.
По программированию особенно касаемо .NET читай про паттерны проектирования. Но в первую очередь читать любые книги по ООП, чтобы раз и навсегда запомнить почему здесь использовано наследование, а не агрегирование. И почему этот метод статический, а здесь конструктор запрещен. Это очень важно чтобы правильно понимать те же самые паттерны. Затем это нужно всё закрепить Макконелом с его книгой Совершенный код. Всё это поможет писать стабильно, ровно и красиво.

Книги по алгоритмизации читать .NET-чику необязательно. т.к. все основные алгоритмы, которые могут понадобится в коммерческих программах уже реализованы внутри .NET. Да и производительные программы пишутся не на .NET.

Comment: Насчёт ненужности алгоритмизации вы всё же погорячились. Простейшие алгоритмы и правда есть в фреймворке, но что угодно нетривиальное придётся кодировать самому. Вот чему можно уделить немного меньше внимания, так это подробностям имплементации структур данных: в .NET есть много различных, хорошо написанных структур данных. (Но знать их свойства всё равно необходимо, чтобы не использовать `List` для всего и не искать полным перебором.)

Comment: >Книги по алгоритмизации читать .NET-чику необязательно. т.к. все основные алгоритмы, которые могут понадобится в коммерческих программах уже реализованы внутри .NET

звучит крайне сомнительно.

Comment: @Антон Лакотко, книги читать, конечно, нужно.

Только надо понимать, что  большинство примеров в них адаптиравано для начинающих.

Поняно, что наследование тема сложная, поэтому в любой книге ей уделяют много места, а на практике агрегирование (композицию) надо по возможности предпочитать наследованию 

(о чем авторы большинства книг для студентов умалчивают (а может и сами не понимают, поскольку давно уже не практикуют)).

Знакомство с паттернами, разумется, полезно. Просто не надо им слепо следовать. Вообще, в последнее время они для многих программистов стали прямо какой-то *религией*.

Comment: @VladD основывался на опыте работы, может быть вы и правы.
@avp я сам паттерны не изучал сразу. И писал код как мне это казалось логичнее и как видел у кого-то другого. А в последствии узнавал про такие вещи как: Одиночка, Фабрика, Адаптер... и удивлялся, почему их подают как нечто крутое.

В любом случае это было моё субъективное мнение.

Comment: Троелсен явно не учит стилю программирования

Answer (score 0):

Скажу достаточно банальзую вещь: нужно просто сесть и начать писать что-то, и по мере расширения задачи брать уже книги, смотреть видеокурсы и сразу же применять изученное на практике. У меня, когда я только начинал учиться, были проекты по реализации игр AD&D и M:tG на С++, и именно они научили меня основам языка.

Comment: Для разных людей подходят разные пути познания... Тут важно для каждого человека найти оптимальный подход, который максимально эффективен для конкретного человека.